# The property contents is set more than once

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

If I use the following `XAML` I get a message to say that the property contents is set more than once.

```xaml
 <telerik:RadTabItem Header="B" x:Name="A">
   <uc:List x:Name="GB" DataContext="{Binding List}" />
   <uc:Grid x:Name="Grid" DataContext="{Binding Numbers}" />
 </telerik:RadTabItem>
```

I can solve this problem by surrounding it with a `StackPanel`.

Are there any another solutions?

Comment: Evidently the `telerik:RadTabItem` class only supports a single child. You need to wrap them in some sort of container (`Grid`, `DockPanel`, `Canvas`, etc.) -- which container you use really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Many WPF `FrameworkElements` can only have one child object. Layout controls like `StackPanel`, `Grid`, `WrapPanel`, etc accept a collection of child objects.  The child objects defined in the `XAML` are assigned to the `Content` property of this control.  It only accepts an object and not a collection of objects, hence your error message (Contents is set more than once)

In the case of the `RadTabItem` you have it does not know how to layout the two controls you have asked it to show.  Should the `List` and `Grid` child controls you have listed be shown side-by-side, top-and-bottom, overlapping, etc?

This is why you need to group the two controls in a container that specifies the layout of the multiple controls in the collection e.g. `StackPanel`, `Grid`, WrapPanel` etc.